# Find next number in array from a input number

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, reduce

For example I have this array:

```js
const array = [5, 9, 12];
```

if input number is `3` it should return `5`,

if input number is `5` it should return `9`,

if input number is `6` it should return `9`,

if input number is `12` it should return `0` or `null` or `undefined`

etc...

I tried using reduce method but with no luck, can't figure out a way.

This is what I got so far, but it will return *closest* number not closest higher :/

```js
const number = arr.reduce((prev, curr) =>
      curr <= input && Math.abs(input - curr) < Math.abs(input - prev) ? curr : prev
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `sort` ( if not sorted initially if sorting is guaranteed you can neglect this step ) the values and use `find` to find any value greater then the passed input.

```js
const array = [5, 9, 12];
const sorted = array.sort((a, b) => a - b)
const numChecker = num => sorted.find(v => v > num)

console.log(numChecker(3))
console.log(numChecker(6))
console.log(numChecker(9))
```

Comment: Why wouldn't I think of such a simple solution, thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you start comparing from 1 index. MDN says:

> Note: If initialValue is not provided, reduce() will execute the callback function starting at index 1, skipping the first index. If initialValue is provided, it will start at index 0.

And there is no need to check the distance(if i understood the task). You can write like this:

```
  const foo = (arr, input) => arr.reduce((prev, curr) =>
    prev <= input ? curr : prev
  );
```

Note: there is no check for the last number in the array